# How position the popup at the beginning of the word - wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Using the following code, I am able to display the popup at caret position how can I open the popup at the beginning of the word. I am using a richtextbox.

```
 Rect positionRect =  richtextbox.CaretPosition.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Backward);
 Point point = richtextbox.PointToScreen(positionRect.BottomRight);
 popup.HorizontalOffset = point.X;
 popup.VerticalOffset = point.Y;
 popup.IsOpen = true;
```

[image]

Comment: Go to start of the word.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan How should I do that, I cannot move the caret position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested below code with `<RichTextBox x:Name="Rtb1"/>` and text in RTB as "stackoverflow is always good". Put cursor at some point and click the button, a popup appears at the start of the word. Now, I used space as word separator, if you want to use (,) or anything else, you can modify it accordingly.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextPointer cur = Rtb1.CaretPosition;
            char[] textbuffer = new char[1];
            do
            {
                int offset = Rtb1.Document.ContentStart.GetOffsetToPosition(cur);
                cur.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Backward, textbuffer, 0, 1);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(textbuffer[0].ToString());
                cur = cur.GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Backward);
            } while (textbuffer[0] != ' ' && cur != null);

            cur = cur.GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
            if (cur == null)
                cur = Rtb1.Document.ContentStart;
            Rtb1.CaretPosition = cur;
            Rtb1.Focus();

            Rect rect = cur.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Backward);
            Point point = Rtb1.PointToScreen(rect.BottomRight);
            Popup1.HorizontalOffset = point.X;
            Popup1.VerticalOffset = point.Y;
            Popup1.IsOpen = true;
        }
```

Please tell if this solves your problem.